# Making jssor carousel real responsive

Tags: jssor

Well, I am not expecting anyone else but jssor himself again to help me out with the best image slider plugin he made(jssor helped me earlier on stackoverflow). I wanted to make the jssor carousel responsive in terms of reducing the number of images shown inside the slide. As of now, the size of the images inside the carousel gets reduced as we move on to smaller resolution devices. However, at some point, this images look real tiny and are not desirable. This issue can be fixed, if we reduce the number of images shown inside the carousel for smaller screens. Like if we are showing 5 images on a larger screen, how do we show only 2 for considerable lower screens?

Waiting on you jssor!!! Keep on the good work you've done!

Answer (score 1):

You know all elements in the slider will scale while window resizing.

As you set small size of your slider, and it scales to bigger size, the arrows looks bigger then.

2 ways to prevent it from scaling bigger.

first, Make the original size of slider bigger, it will prevent the slider from displaying with large scale ratio.

second, Suppress the arrows from scaling explicitly with `data-noscale="1"`.

```
<span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora13l" style="top:0px;left:30px;width:40px;height:50px;" data-noscale="1"></span>
<span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora13r" style="top:0px;right:30px;width:40px;height:50px;" data-noscale="1"></span>
```

Example: [suppress arrows from scaling - jssor slider](http://www.jssor.com/jssordev/sliders/prevent-arrows-from-scaling-explicitly.slider)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but please take a look at the question again. You've answered to what I asked on email and this question is quite different.

Comment: Jssor slider initializes with fixed number of slides. For now, there is no option to add/remove slide dynamically.